# How to tame vim's ":find" command

Tags: vim

Say, I have files foo.js and bar.css in my project. There is a ":find" command in vim, which find files, matching string. But this command, alas, has some limitations. For example, if I launch this way - "vim", or even this way - "vim ." - there's nothing to be find in js subdirectory. But if I launch vim this way - "vim js/any_file_other_than_foo.js", then calling ":find foo.js" works pretty well.

Since it is not intuitive (i'm working in the same directory, "pwd" returns the same path), my first question is - can anybody explain how to circumvent this issue? And, even broader, is there any way to type something like find foo - and open first file, which name matches pattern foo.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice plugin that accomplishes a similar effect is [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025).

> The Command-T plug-in provides an
>   extremely fast, intuitive mechanism
>   for opening files with a minimal
>   number of keystrokes. It's named
>   "Command-T" because it is inspired by
>   the "Go to File" window bound to
>   Command-T in TextMate.
>
> Files are selected by typing
>   characters that appear in their paths,
>   and are ordered by an algorithm which
>   knows that characters that appear in
>   certain locations (for example,
>   immediately after a path separator)
>   should be given more weight.should be given more weight.

Here is a [screencast](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) of Command-T in action.

Comment: it's a pity that such an awesome plug-in demands vim, compiled with ruby

Comment: @shabunc, then you could try [lookupfile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1581) it's only dependency is another vimscript. (Although it's not the same as Cmd-T)

Answer (score 7):

You could try

`:e[dit] **/*foo*` and then press 'tab' to move to the first match.

the `**` is a directory globbing pattern, while `*` is character matching.

If you were so inclined, you could write a simple fuzzy finder command, for more information you can check out the vim tips wiki: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_files_in_subdirectories

Comment: okay zed, actually, it's not that simple. calling :e with wildcard will open all matches.

Comment: I should have been more clear that pressing 'tab' will allow you to open only the first match.

Comment: You'd probably want to use `set wildmenu` so you can see the matches you're scrolling through. See also `:help wildmode`

Answer (score 4):

Vim's `:find` works by searching each directory in the `path` variable (and ignores pwd). By default, it does **not** search recursively. That's why find is only working for you when you open a js file. The '.' in path refers to the directory for the current file -- not pwd.

You can change path to include your desired directories:

```
set path+=$PROJECT/js
```

See `:help path`.

One of the magic bits to use is to add ** to a path to search that path recursively:

```
" search recursively in my project
set path+=$PROJECT/**
" search recursively from the current file's directory
set path+=./**
```

See `:help file-searching` for more magic.